# ReSharper slow and troublesome

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Im using ReSharper 6 in a Vs 2010 Pro environment and are doing some pretty large scale projects. Development box includes 2 x quadcore xeon with 24 GB ram. Project's are running on a PCI-E x4 SSD drive with 1GB/s read and write (for real). So, i suppose there is not much I can do to give the development machine more power.

The worst project is an Umbraco site with roughly 14000 files and folders and some pretty nasty css. I got everything from second long freezes to 30 sec VS freezout.

I've optimized VS2010 according to every guide available in VS optimization. Even enabled the 64bit memory enhancement but the problems continue.

I've even added the media library folder to the skip list.

Are there any other magic tricks someone would know of, please let me know!

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be "project with 14000 files slow and troublesome." I'd look at splitting that up.

Comment: What is the 64bit memory enhancement you applied? I'm quite curious about it.

Comment: TrueWill: True, if it wasn't for the hardware i'd say so but when disabling ReSharper everything runs extremely well. Piers: In the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE you should run > editbin /largeaddressaware devenv.exe

Comment: Please try a 6.1 build from nightly builds (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.1+Nightly+Builds). If it doesn't get any better than with 6.0, please a performance profiling snapshot to JetBrains for investigation (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Profiling+Instructions). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gorohoroh's comment lead me to the solution, the 6.1 nightly dec 13 rocks!

Thanks

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.1+Nightly+Builds

Answer (score 2):

I am using 7.0.1 and I find that it's killing my machine too.

However, it normally happens if I have more than one VS2010 open.

If it happens then the only way of fixing it I have found is to close VS, delete the DotSettings.user and the suo, and then reopen.

Comment: +1 All refatorings and Find Usages where taking ages after upgrading to Resharper 7, and this was the only solution that worked!  Would like to know why it gets into this state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 6.1, and find that it slows down over time, and typing becomes really laggy. I've just discovered that when it starts to chug, if I go to "Tools..Options..ReSharper..General", then click on Suspend, then Resume - it goes back to it's initial speed.